# android volley request never happens

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I m android beginner, can anoyone help me with my problem, I need to make Volley request synchronous. I found solution, I sholud use RequestFuture, but response never happens. Can you tell me where is mistake...

```
  RequestFuture<JSONArray> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    Images = new ArrayList<>();

    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl, future, future) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("catalogID", s);

            return params;
        }

    };

    try {

        JSONArray response = future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Log.e("test", "test");
        int length = response.length();
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {


            jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);


            String path = jsonObject.getString("Path");
            Images.add(path);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It just stuck, nothing happend, and this Log.e("test", "test") never appears, but if I put some Log.e before JSONArray response = future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); then that Log above appears.

Comment: It's because your code goes to one the catch clauses. Try to put log on every catch clause, or debug your code, so you will know the error.